# Nginx HttpUploadProgressModule not working as expected

Tags: nginx

I have Nginx sat in front of Apache. I have Nginx compiled with HttpUploadProgressModule

```
location / {
                root /var/www/site/domains/www.somewhere.com/public_html;
                proxy_pass         http://123.123.123.123:8080;
                proxy_redirect     default;
                proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                client_max_body_size       500m;
                client_body_buffer_size    128k;
                proxy_connect_timeout      90;
                proxy_send_timeout         900;
                proxy_read_timeout         900;
                proxy_buffer_size   4k;
                proxy_buffers              4 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                charset         off;
                track_uploads proxied 30s;
            }

location ^~ /admin/include/get_upload_status.php  {
                report_uploads proxied;
            }
```

Now when I hit this location from a webbrowser I just get dished up the php file for download instead of the file upload report.

This is my first run in with HttpUploadProgressModule and I'm stuck at what to try.

Answer (score 0):

I got some sound advise off great dude in the nginx irc and that was that nginx will only ever use one location `location ^~ /admin/include/get_upload_status.php` was matching but then not getting passed back to the apache server, I had to proxy_pass again in the `location ^~ /admin/include/get_upload_status.php`